# How to format json for chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

So, I want to output json from my controller that chart.js can read and then display as a graph.

my query in controller returns two columns (I'm using dapper). 1st one will be on x-axis and next one on y-axis. It's just a simple bar chart.

I believe chart.js needs two arrays one for each axis.

something like.

x[x axis values]

y[ y axis values]

How do I output json that chart.js can read? Do I need to create a viewmodel for this or can this be done right inside the controller?

I know that if I create a viewmodel and then pass that as list then it will output the model as json object but as I said that's not really the format chart.js expects.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult count()
    {
        List<string> indexList = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new g))
            {
                indexList = db.Query<> blablbka

            }
            return Json(indexList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }


    }
```

Sample chart.js
labels and data both come from database through that query. label is year and data is count of events for each particular year.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [20,10,9,8,5,2],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us what you are creating so we know what data you want (e.g. an example with hard coded values for your bar chart)

Comment: added example. Thanks.

Comment: And which values do you want from the controller? - just the array for `labels: ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"],` and `data: [20,10,9,8,5,2],`?

Comment: yes I think that's all a bar chart needs

Comment: Then it would be `return Json(new { labels = new string[]{ "2010", "2011", ... }, data = new int[]{ 20,10, ... } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and in your ajax call assign those to variables which then then use to set the Chart options.

Comment: this is not a fixed data but it's coming from the database. My sql query returns two columns one is for year and next is count of events for that year. How do I get this format to output as json?

Comment: I'm using dapper for sql query btw

Comment: I know. I gave you ans example - we have no idea what your data is, or what your model is, or what properties contain the data you want!

Comment: I don't have a model for this but I guess I can create one but it  seems unnecessary to create dozens of models if I have dozens of graphs. Can't this just be done from within the controller?

Comment: Of course - you create a query to select the data you want and project it to an anonymous object

Comment: can you give an example? I have no idea what an anonymous object is.

Comment: I just gave you an example of an anonymous object in the code above. You question is too broad an not answerable

Comment: ok thanks. I'm just confused since dapper returns what's essentially a data table and then maps those columns to objects if given a model. the only other option is built-in types like list<string> or something but that probably requires one list for each axis.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net will serialize any object given to its Json method as a json string, you just have to make sure the serialized object matches what chart.js is expecting.

For example, if I have an object like this

```
[Serializable]
public class ChartJsData{
    public string Foo {get;set;}
    public int[] Bar {get;set;}
}
```

And I give it to the Json method

```
var chartData = new ChartJsData(){
    Foo = "FooVal",
    Bar = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}
}
return Json(chartData);
```

Then the controller action will return the json string

```
{ Foo: "FooVal", Bar: [1,2,3,4,5] }
```

Disclaimer: I have not run this and there could be some missing quotes or something, but this is the general idea

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back. This still needs for me to create a viewmodel though for each graph. I was hoping that perhaps this can done right inside the controller.

Comment: Adding `[Serializable]` might not be necessary since it might mess up the JSON serialization (e.g. in .NET 4.0's WebAPI )